# jQuery conditional based on multiple selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two IDs and I would like to create a condition based on my query.

```
$("#foo", "#bar").foo.bar({
  baz: function() {
    if(selector == "#foo") {
      console.log("foo");
    } else {
      console.log("bar");
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: `$("#foo, #bar")` - comma separate selectors within the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go so well?

```js
var x = $('.foo, .bar');
if(x.hasClass('foo')){
  // True!
} else {
  // false!
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#foo, #bar").foo.bar({
  baz: function() {
    if(selector.prop('id') == "foo") {
      console.log("foo");
    } else {
      console.log("bar");
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply separate into two statements:

```
$("#foo").foo.bar({
  baz: function() {
    console.log("foo");
  }
});

$("#bar").foo.bar({
  baz: function() {
    console.log("bar");
  }
});
```